# Capturing and storing a value from the output of a shell script while also displaying progress?

Tags: bash, shell

I use a bash script from an upstream repo that echos the high level progress as it goes through the script.  At the end it displays a path/filename for the results of the script.  I'm trying to get that path/file name without modifying the script since the script changes frequently.  I can't figure out how to get the path/filename.

- If I pipe the output through `grep` then I lose the progress output text.
- If I use `awk` with a regex to match I also lose the progress output text.
- With a wrapper script, assigning a variable to the output of command subscription with `sed`, is failing and I don't know if it is the match, the command substitution, or the wrong tool for the job.

I've spent a lot of time and thought now might be a good time to ask:

*How should I do this?*

Here's a sample just to demonstrate the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The directory to be analyzed abc123/def456/"
echo "## CPU"
echo "## Messages"
echo "## Out of Memory"
echo "Calling other script..."
echo "Done."
echo
echo "## Please check out the file /tmp/report_user1/def456-2020-12-02.log"
```

Output.   I'm trying to grab the path/filename from the last line.

```
The directory to be analyzed abc123/def456/
## CPU
## Messages
## Out of Memory
Calling other script...
Done.

## Please check out the file /tmp/report_user1/def456-2020-12-02.log
```

Thank-you.

Comment: Where do you want the script output to go? same Q for the last line?

Comment: @Milag Script output to stdout as it does now.  I  want to copy the .log file to the current directory and then have it opened by my text editor.

Comment: I can post a working prototype; for now try this as a wrapper script:  `var=$(main-script | tee /dev/tty | grep '\.log$'); echo "var $var"`

Comment: Send the status updates to stderr and the final output to stdout?

Comment: @Milag  That works great.  Thanks so much!
Do you want to create an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: Welcome. OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view stdout on your terminal **plus** capture / filter, one method without tmp files is piping the output from any [utility or script] into `tee /dev/tty`, along with piping the `tee` output to a filter, eg:

```
util | tee /dev/tty | grep '\.log$'
```

capturing the above to a bash variable:

```
var=$(util | tee /dev/tty | grep '\.log$')
```

From the OP's description the above could be scripted, `tee` output could reduced by other methods, log file copied, then exec `$EDITOR ./copy.log`